# Prescedence in the case of if not "a" == "b"

Tags: lua

```
function test()
  if not "a" == "b" then
    print("the strings are different")
  end
end
```

It seems I have this error all over my file. Lua pulls the `not` stronger than the `==`, and interprets that I'm asking whether `"a"` is a nil value. I understand that `not` has higher precedence than `==`, but how can Lua just ignore the rest of the line? Shouldn't it notice that there's more coming there and throw an error that `== "b"` doesn't fit into the syntax?

Comment: It __does__ fit into the syntax. It `==`-compares the result of `not "a"` with `"b"`.

Comment: `not "a" == "b"` --> `(not "a") == "b"` --> `false == "b"`

Comment: Instead of `not x == y`, use `x ~= y`.

Comment: What about the case `not ("a" == "b" or "c" == "d")`? Will these require nested parenthesis, i.e. does it apply the not in the same way as above once in the parenthesis? (I don't want to do `x ~= y`, because I'm comparing objects where I'm not entirely sure they have a negative comparison.)

Comment: maybe you should ask about the problem you're actually trying to solve rather than to think about logical expressions with constants that always resolve to the same value.

Comment: @JohnBig: `not` is simply a [unary operator](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.8) that always returns `true` or `false`. The stuff in parentheses will be evaluated before applying any outside operator. That expression is unusual, because it can easily be simplified using [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): `'a' ~= 'b' and 'c' ~= 'd'`. Note that comparison operators all have direct opposites, which sometimes makes the `not` unnecessary.

Comment: @Piglet: I simplified it for your convenience. The essence of the question is present in what I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine as many values as you like with [logical operators](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.5). Unless you use parenthesis Lua will use operator precedence to determin what to evaluate first.

> Lua pulls the not stronger than the ==, and interprets that I'm asking
> whether "a" is a nil value. I understand that not has higher
> precedence than ==

Correct. That's why Lua evaluates`not "a" == "b"` as `(not "a") == "b"` which resolves to `false == "b"` and finally to `false`.

If you want to check wether two values are unequal use the unequal operator `~=`.

> Shouldn't it notice that there's more coming there and throw an error
> that == "b" doesn't fit into the syntax?

No because this is correct syntax. You just used an expression that doesn't get what you want.

> What about the case not ("a" == "b" or "c" == "d")? Will these require
> nested parenthesis, i.e. does it apply the not in the same way as
> above once in the parenthesis?

`not ("a" == "b" or "c" == "d")` resolves to `true`.

`or` has the lowest precedence. So you don't need further parenthesis. You should probably work mit more realistic examples because those strings will never be equal.

> (I don't want to do x ~= y, because I'm
> comparing objects where I'm not entirely sure they have a negative
> comparison.)

I can't make sense of this.

Comment: I think that last part means they're using variables instead of strings. I guess they're using strings in the examples, because it's easier to make an MRE that way.

Comment: The objects I'm comparing are userdata objects from a video game, and I'm not sure a "not equals" is defined for them. I just want to exclude an error source by not using `~=`.

Comment: @JohnBig: If `==` is defined, so is `~=`, so you don't have to worry about that. I confirmed this with both Lua 5.4 and LuaJIT.